# How to get data from 2 tables?

Tags: php, join

I am trying to create a website with an existing database.
The database has two tables, one of them contain the post info like title, id, content, etc etc,
the other table contains the post ID and the post category.

For example: I want to take a post from a specific category.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status = "publish" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10';
```

This is a simple function, can some one help me please how to modify it, to get the category from the other table and the post info from the other table.

Comment: Please take time to lean basic SQL - it will be really useful for your future [for example, from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts, posts_category WHERE category = 'category' 
AND 
status = 'publish'
AND
posts_category.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Hello , thank you for your answer. My database has about 80.000 rows, is this method a bit "heavy" to get the result i want ?

Comment: @Meo - this is no less efficient than an explicit join. Just make sure the appropriate columns are indexed (post_id, category, status) and your table can grow to 8 million rows no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status = 'publish' AND pid IN (SELECT pid FROM pcategory WHERE ptype='category_name') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
```